# Fire javascript when hovering an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the `html` below. You can see a [live](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjyLQN?editors=101) version.
As you can see I have multiples `<h3>` elements, with names, and when you click on the name, a sublist shows up with `SlideToggle()`.
I need to active this click effect when hovering that object for 2 seconds.
I need to replicate the click effect when I'm hovering that element.
I could do it with the `click` event, but I can't figure out a way to do it to all `<h3` elements using the `hover` effect.

```
   <li>
      <h3 data-id="3" class="prof-name">Sigmund Berge 
      <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="check_prof">
      </h3>
     <ul class="list-disc ui-sortable" id="oi" style="display: none;">
        <li data-dia="seg" data-time="08:30:00" data-id="1" class="ui-sortable-handle">Lab I</li>
        <li data-dia="ter" data-time="10:30:00" data-id="2" class="ui-sortable-handle">Lab II</li>                                      
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
     <h3 data-id="4" class="prof-name">Eusebio Rice 
       <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="check_prof">
     </h3>              
    <ul class="list-disc ui-sortable">
       <li data-dia="sex" data-time="18:30:00" data-id="5" class="ui-sortable-handle">Estatistica</li>
       <li data-dia="seg" data-time="08:30:00" data-id="6" class="ui-sortable-handle">Calculo A</li>

    </ul>
 </li>

 <li>
    <h3 data-id="5" class="prof-name">Dr. Andy Bailey 
      <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="check_prof">
    </h3>

    <ul class="list-disc ui-sortable">
       <li data-dia="qua" data-time="14:30:00" data-id="3" class="ui-sortable-handle">Engenharia de Software</li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
   <h3 data-id="6" class="prof-name">Mr. Durward Crooks I 
     <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="check_prof">
   </h3>

 </li>
</ul>
```

I could get the desire effect but only hard coding the element's ID (just for test) and it worked:

```
//HOVER effect


<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var old_teacher;
            $('.list-disc').sortable({
                connectWith: '.list-disc',

                over: function(event, ui){
                    var timeoutId;
                    $(".prof-name").hover(function(event) {
                        var $obj = event.target;
                        if (!timeoutId) {
                            timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
                                timeoutId = null;
                                console.log($(this));
                           }, 2000);
                        }
                    },
                    function (event) {
                        if (timeoutId) {
                            window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
                            timeoutId = null;
                        }
                        else {
                           $(event.target).next().slideToggle();
                        }
                    });
                },

                start: function (event, ui){
                    old_teacher = ui.item.parent().prev().attr('data-id');
                },
                stop: function (event, ui){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '{{ URL::to("/professor") }}',
                        data: { disciplina: ui.item.attr('data-id'), professor: ui.item.parent().prev().attr('data-id'), old: old_teacher },
                        success: function(data){
                        },
                        error: function(data){
                            console.log( old_teacher);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        })
</script>
```

You will see the hard code here:

```
$("h3[data-id='3']").hover
```

I can't do that of course. So how may I do that dynamically ??

Answer (score 1):

On `mouseenter` start the timeout, on `mouseleave` clear the timeout.
If the timeout reaches it's end point, just use `$hoveredElSelector.trigger("click")` if you already have a `click` function bound to that element.

---

You could also create your functions first, and always start the timeout, both on click or `mouseenter mouseleave` ( the `.hover()`) - just using a `0` timeout for the click:

```
function ANIM() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle( $.proxy(CLEAR,this) );
}

function CLEAR() {
  return clearTimeout( this.timeout );
}

function SET() {
  this.timeout = setTimeout( $.proxy(ANIM,this), event.type==="click"?0:2000 );
}

$("h2").click(ANIM).hover(SET, CLEAR);
```

***[Here's a live example](https://jsbin.com/mogasi/3/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

Comment: Could you give me an example? `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are events like click ?

Answer (score 1):

You have many options for achieving this, imo the two most basic methods being:

**1.)** Use a class selector for binding the `.hover` event. Looks like you can use `prof-name`:

```
$(".prof-name").hover
```

**2.)** Use delegation if the elements are loaded periodically, you would probably want to add a wrapper class:

```
<div class='wrapper'>

...

   <li>
      <h3 data-id="3" class="prof-name">Sigmund Berge 
      <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="check_prof">
      </h3>
     <ul class="list-disc ui-sortable" id="oi" style="display: none;">
        <li data-dia="seg" data-time="08:30:00" data-id="1" class="ui-sortable-handle">Lab I</li>
        <li data-dia="ter" data-time="10:30:00" data-id="2" class="ui-sortable-handle">Lab II</li>                                      
     </ul>
  </li>

...

</div>
```

Then use something like:

```
$(".wrapper").on('hover', '.prof-name', function(){

});
```

Comment: Tried to write something in `console.log()`. Didnt work.

Comment: which method did you try? Class or Delegation? I'm not sure how you are loading/creating the elements + handlers you might NEED to use delegation in order for it to work properly

Comment: I'm trying to use this while drag/drop an element, I want to drag an element and hover the mouse for two seconds to apply the `slideToggle` function.

Comment: without seeing your code it's hard for me to diagnose `console.log() didn't work`... :/

Comment: You're right. Just updated the whole script code. I tried inside that `over` also inside a `drag`.